# How to stop angular 6 firestore listener

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
 ngOnInit() {    

        this.firestore.collection('mycollection').ref.where("myfiled","==","animal") 

            .onSnapshot((data=>{}));
}
```

This is my code and it will run multiple time if I visit other pages
for example, Above code is in page1 and if I visit  page2 then returns to page1 then it will call 2 times and again if visit page3 and return to page one then it will call 3 times.
 How to fix it?

Comment: I am guessing you need to unsubscribe

Comment: That is correct. but How to do that?

Comment: I am not sure if the .onSnapShot() returns an Observable or Subscription, but you can in your ngDestroy-method do the unsubscribe. Store the call in a variable, then do variableName.unsubscribe()

Comment: not working still now it is calling multiple time

Comment: Did you implement OnDestroy in your component?

Comment: The OnDestroy will be called when you change page. And OnInit when you go back, you can then reuse the sam component as you wish, but the subscription will not run many times

Comment: not working i called on ondestroy

Comment: the problem is data is not duplicating the proble  is i don't no how to distrot firestore lisiner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First implement `OnDestroy` in your component. The `ngOnDestroy` will be called when you change page.

Then you can unsubscribe like this:

```
this.unsubscribe = this.firestore.collection("mycollection")
  .ref.where("myfiled","==","animal")
  .onSnapshot((data=>{
    // Your code
  }));
```

And in the `ngOnDestroy`:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  // Stop listening to changes
  this.unsubscribe();
}
```

Check [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener) for more informations.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time until I figured it out in angular and firestore 9. Here is the complete code:

```
unsubscribe: any = null

ngOnDestroy() {
// Stop listening to changes
this.unsubscribe();
}

startListening() {
// some code to configure listening here
if (this.unsubscribe() != null) { // I detach listener and attach it again
      this.unsubscribe()
}
this.unsubscribe = onSnapshot(query, (snapshot) => {
// code processing changes in collection
})
}
```

In my case I needed to change parameters of the listener. This is why I detach and attach listener again in startListening()

Answer (score -1):

`firestore.collection` gives you `unsubscribe` method. Just assign this code to variable and unsubscribe it in OnDestroy method

Comment: I can only guess that there is problem with interface of `this.firestore`, can you paste somewhere whole code?